# Issues with pandas function read_html

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping

I am trying to get all the tables from the site: https://www.hockey-reference.com/players/o/ovechal01-advanced.html.

When I use read_html(url) it only returns the table on the top of that site, when I want all of them. What is the problem here, can someone help me?